# how can i change the permanent from permalinks (wordpress)

Tags: permalinks

how can i change the permanent from permalink structure without change the site address (url)

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Do you want to show your content under a different domain name or what are you trying to do here?

Comment: yes i want to show content under a different domain name in proxy server

Comment: You might need a multisite installation for this. Check out https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/

Comment: Check this plugin, may be it is what you need: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/